# Image preloader one by one for gallery? What is wrong with this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a JavaScript (jQuery), HTML gallery, which has like 60 pictures. I want them to load one by one. They are named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg... etc.

So I started with making a `<img id="loader" style="display:none;" src=""/>`
this contains the actually loading image, I give src for it with a script, then wait for it to load, then give the same src to its real destination:

`<img class="active_pic" id="a1" src="img/load.gif"/>`

When it is done I start loading the second picture. How do I do that?

I tried making it with a recursion, a function which calls itself, but it wouldn't wait for the image to load. I used this:

```
$("#loader").attr("src",pic);   
$("#loader").ready(function(){$("#a"+active).attr("src",pic);
```

Comment: Try http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/ it's a cross browser solution to wait for images to be load.

Comment: how much time is taking for a pic to load? use `setInterval(function() {/*load picture here*/}, 3000)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your images from JS code with

```
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
    // do stuff after image is loaded
};

img.src = pic_url;
```

### Update

JS function stub and usage example

```
<script>
function load_image(img_url)
{
    // show overlay, spinner, whatever

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        // add <img> tag
        // hide overlay, spinner, whatever
    };
    img.src = img_url;
}
</script>

<a href="jaavscript:load_image('/images/test.jpg');">load image</a>
```

Comment: But will it wait for the picture to load, or will it just skip img.onload = function() {  because it is not true yet?

Comment: `onload` will trigger only after image is loaded. So put loading other image inside that callabck.

Comment: and img.onload can be in an other function which is called at a onclick event?

Comment: Of course it can. But what really is triggering loading of image is assignment of `img.src`. `onload` should be defined before it.

Comment: it is better if img.src is before img.onload right? so it can load, and then check if it is loaded.

Comment: No, it must be the way I showed. `onload` is the callback when image is loaded it must be registered before actial load is triggered and it's triggered when assigning `img.src` property.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the onload event of the picture. But if your image is cached it will not work, so you can use it:

```
$('img[id|="a"]').each(function() {
    if(this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');
});

var doOnLoad=function(){
    var id=parseInt($(this).attr('id').substr(1));
    $(this).removeClass("active_pic");
    id++;
    $('#a'+id).attr("src",pic[id]).one('load', doOnLoad).addClass("active_pic");
};

$(".active_pic").one('load', doOnLoad);
```

pic must be an array with id as key and src as value.